# How to use django channels js_client in angular 2+

Tags: angular, django-channels

Probably trivial question but how can I install/use 
https://github.com/django/channels/tree/master/js_client
in my angualar2+ app?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple... :
`yarn add django-channels`